# Javascript reading firebase list data

Tags: callback, firebase

I'm trying to read firebase data and then print the data to the console, but nothing makes it to the console.

```
function readData(){
var listRef = new Firebase('https://----.firebaseIO.com/');

    listRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {

    var msgData = snapshot.val();
    console.log("Snapshot : " + msgData.message);

    });//end snapshot


}//end readData
```

my firebase data looks like. This is right under the root.

```
{
"-J75NmiNt3blUhVDCWbc" : {
"from" : "Blah",
"message" : "Blah"
},
"-J75N2bNbDZpshEBG1yS" : {
"from" : "Jackson",
"message" : "BLAH  BlaH"
},
"-J75PCsjFlbDQ3g9vKyb" : {
"from" : "fff",
"message" : "fff"
},
"-J75MvQQpRBB6s-l3KrQ" : {
"from" : "",
"message" : ""
},
"-J75OHX7rdE1K8wpvZOt" : {
"from" : "fff",
"message" : "ff"
}
} //end
```

Comment: Are you ever calling the `readData` function?

Comment: Yes I'm calling it on a button

Comment: Do you know it's actually being called? Your function looks fine.

Comment: The function is definitely getting called, if I put an alert right before the snapshot, the alert shows up.

Comment: @user2758113 And if you put the `alert` just after the `console.log` call it should probably still work?  If `console.log` failed it is either throwing an error, or the values are null... just best guess.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT:** My original answer was completely missing question, rewritten for further smiting

Are you sure that you are getting the data within your Event?  It would gracefully fail.  Step through the debugger and make sure you are getting your actual object passed correctly.  From their example on the chat tool They are binding to an event that pushes to the `listRef` object like this:

```
$('#messageInput').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var name = $('#nameInput').val();
    var text = $('#messageInput').val();
    messagesRef.push({name:name, text:text});
    $('#messageInput').val('');
  }
});
```

My guess is that your `snapshot` variable is not accessible/null.

Comment: I understand the asynchronous issue.  But why wouldn't this firebase docs example work? 

[the reading the data part at the bottom](https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-lists.html)

Comment: @user2758113 Ouch, you are absolutely right.  Its an event, my mistake... I used the example from their chat client and it worked great.  Have you checked your data?

Comment: Well the example from the chat client works fine with my data set, so I guess I'll just use that, since i need to be posting and getting.